# php fgetcsv and integer conversion (UTF8 x UCS-2 Little Endian)

Tags: php, fgetcsv

**UPDATE 4:**

I've found (as suspected) that the files enconding is responsible for this. I converted the csv file from UCS-2 Little Endian to UTF-8 and everything works fine. Anyway I need to find some way to make PHP understands the input file correctly. Tried already `sellocale` without success.

--- original question ---

I have some data stored on a csv file in 'table' format and I want to store this data as (tag, tagtimestamp, tagvalue) on a database. But can't find a way to cast values stored on $v array to integer values:

```
$p=0;
$tag=array();
$dt=array();
$v=array();

$handle=fopen("sga/2013.10.054.vol2.csv", "r");

while(($row=fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t"))!==FALSE){
    $num=count($row);
    $num--; // only even collumns
    if($p==0){
        for($c=1; $c<$num; $c+=2){
            array_push($tag, $row[$c]);
        }
    }else{
        array_push($dt, $row[0]);
        for($c=1; $c<$num;$c+=2){
            array_push($v, $row[$c]); // <<< here is my problem
        }
    }
    $p++;
}
fclose($handle);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($v);
echo "</pre>";
```

echoes:

```
Array(
[0] => 8701
[1] => 5281
[2] => 4341
[3] => 4360
[4] => 8701
[5] => 8239
[6] => 4631
[7] => 4115
[8] => 4123
[9] => 8239
[10] => 8409
[11] => 3978
[12] => 4192
[13] => 4216
[14] => 8409
[15] => 8916
[16] => 3325
[17] => 4444
[18] => 4472
[19] => 8916
[20] => 9550
[21] => 3286
[22] => 4763
[23] => 4789
```

...

tried to use

```
(int)$row[$c], 
intval($row[$c]), 
($row[$c]+0), 
settype($row[$c], "integer")
preg_replace('!\s+!', $row[$c]) // to clean up any messy char...
```

, etc...

I do interpolate values using:

```
$nv=0;
$sqls="";
foreach ($tag as $kt=>$t){
    foreach($dt as $kd=>$d){
        $f=($kd*5)+$kt;
        $de=explode(" ", $d);
        $d=implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $de[0])))." ".$de[1];
        $nv=$v[$f]; // <<<<< here the values must become integers but only returns zeroes
        $sqls.="('$t', '$d', $nv), ";
    }
}
```

// the final query is setted here

```
    $sql="";
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO aducao (tag, tagtime, tagvalue) VALUES "; 
$sqls=rtrim($sqls, ", ");
$sql.=$sqls;
echo $sql;
```

My file is UTF.8 without BOM formated.

and CSV file is tab (\t) separated.

Anyway if I left the "values" as it comes from csv my mysql database throws an error, and if I try to convert the values becomes zeroes.

**UPDATE:**

here's the mysql error if values is not converted. I guess that because if I copy and paste the sql string directly on mysql query browser the error does not occur, so some type of 'dirt' is into these values...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

**UPDATE 2:**

var_dump($v) shows:

```
array(3725) { [0]=> string(9) "8701" [1]=> string(9) "5281" [2]=> string(9) "4341" [3]=> string(9) "4360" [4]=> string(9) "8701" [5]=> string(9) "8239" [6]=> string(9) "4631" [7]=> string(9) "4115" [8]=> string(9) "4123" [9]=> string(9) "8239" [10]=> string(9) "8409" [11]=> string(9) "3978" [12]=> string(9) "4192" [13]=> string(9) "4216" [14]=> string(9) "8409" [15]=> string(9) "8916" [16]=> string(9) "3325" [17]=> string(9) "4444" [18]=> string(9) "4472" [19]=> string(9) "8916" [20]=> string(9) "9550" [21]=> string(9) "3286" [22]=> string(9) "4763" [23]=> string(9) "4789" [24]=> string(9) "9550" [25]=> string(11) "11506" [26]=> string(9) "3448" [27]=> string(9) "5738" [28]=> string(9) "5769" [29]=> string(11) "11506" [30]=> string(11) "11287" [31]=> string(9) "3690" [32]=> string(9) "5630" [33]=> string(9) "5656" [34]=> string(11) "11287" [35]=> string(11) "10639" [36]=> string(9) "4329" [37]=> string(9) "5312" [38]=> string(9) "5327" [39]=> string(11) "10639" [40]=> string(11) "11427" [41]=> string(9) "4973" [42]=> string(9) "5704" [43]=> string(9) "5721" [44]=> string(11) "11427" [45]=> string(11) "11688" [46]=> string(9) "5605" [47]=> string(9) "5841" [48]=> string(9) "5847"
```

**UPDATE 3:**

part of $sql output

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO aducao (tag, tagtime, tagvalue) VALUES ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 00:00:00', 8701), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 01:00:00', 8239), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 02:00:00', 8409), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 03:00:00', 8916), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 04:00:00', 9550), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 05:00:00', 11506), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 06:00:00', 11287), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 07:00:00', 10639), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 08:00:00', 11427), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 09:00:00', 11688), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 10:00:00', 7973), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 11:00:00', 2067), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 12:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 13:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 14:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 15:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 16:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 17:00:00', 137), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 18:00:00', 142), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 19:00:00', 140), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 20:00:00', 169), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 21:00:00', 0), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 22:00:00', 161), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-01 23:00:00', 9275), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 00:00:00', 7679), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 01:00:00', 8996), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 02:00:00', 9135), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 03:00:00', 9569), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 04:00:00', 10114), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 05:00:00', 10612), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 06:00:00', 10438), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 07:00:00', 10945), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 08:00:00', 11784), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 09:00:00', 12355), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 10:00:00', 12500), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 11:00:00', 12045), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 12:00:00', 12089), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 13:00:00', 12413), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 14:00:00', 13024), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 15:00:00', 13444), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 16:00:00', 12244), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 17:00:00', 10139), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 18:00:00', 8586), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 19:00:00', 8146), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 20:00:00', 8418), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 21:00:00', 8857), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 22:00:00', 9142), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-02 23:00:00', 9296), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-03 00:00:00', 10015), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-03 01:00:00', 9256), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-03 02:00:00', 9452), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-03 03:00:00', 11136), ('E054_VOL', '2013-10-03 04:00:00', 110)
```

Comment: That SQL error doesn't help much without the actual query. You didn't tag the question as SQL but if the error is occurring in a query then that's probably where you should be casting. That's the more secure place to do it too.

Comment: In response to your updated question: What's your query look like?  What does `var_dump($sqls);` output (outside the loop)?

Comment: What does `echo $sql` output? That's what I was looking for, the exact query string sent to the MySQL server.

Comment: array_push($v, (int) $row[$c]);

Comment: @Jasper in fact if I paste the sql output on mysql query browser the sql is executed without error. So the problem occurs only when executed inside php using mysql_query($sql).

Comment: @mcuadros indeed I tried that one. Doing that returns 0 for all values.

Comment: @PauloBueno I'm not familiar with the `IGNORE` flag(?) you're using. What's its purpose?

Comment: @Jasper -IGNORE- means that mysql will silent fail in cases where the primary key rule is broken. For the purpose of this question it has no influence thought.

Comment: @PauloBueno My last piece of advice is to remove the IGNORE flag and see what you get.

Comment: As you found out, `fgetcsv()` does indeed rely on the system's locale. Is the locale you are trying to switch to available on your system? (type `locale -a` in your console)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your var_dump output it looks like PHP has read some unprintable/invisible characters. That is why you see `string(9) "8409"`, where you can clearly count that there are only 4 digits and not 9.

What I would do in your situation:

1) understand whether the values are correct.

2) use some hex viewer/editor and open the file to see what characters are actually there.

3) one of the solutions is probably just to remove all the unneeded (invisible) characters by a simple `preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $value);` and then insert them in a SQL query.

Comment: Hi @Ingus, I've awarded your answer, but unfornately I didn't tested it already. ASAP I'll accept your answer if it work. ty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you convert all values of $v to numeric

```
<?php

//call array function to walk on each element of $v array and convert it to numeric value
array_walk($v, 'convert_to_num');

function convert_to_num(&$value, $key) {

    $value = $value * 1;


}

var_dump($v);

?>
```